# Blockchain API call output object name instead of content

Tags: python

The following code produce the following output. You will probably tell me that it is normal. I don't understand how I can print the content instead of just the object name. Any contribution is appreciated.

```
def get_address(address, filter=None, limit=None, offset=None, api_code=None):
    resource = 'address/{0}?format=json'.format(address)
    if filter is not None:
        if isinstance(filter, FilterType):
            resource += '&filter=' + str(filter.value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Filter must be of FilterType enum')
    if limit is not None:
        resource += '&limit=' + str(limit)
    if offset is not None:
        resource += '&offset=' + str(offset)
    if api_code is not None:
        resource += '&api_code=' + api_code
    response = util.call_api(resource)
    json_response = json.loads(response)
    return Address(json_response)

class Address:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.hash160 = a['hash160']
        self.address = a['address']
        self.n_tx = a['n_tx']
        self.total_received = a['total_received']
        self.total_sent = a['total_sent']
        self.final_balance = a['final_balance']
        self.transactions = [Transaction(tx) for tx in a['txs']]

address = TestGetAddress('********************************')
```

output:

```
<__main__.Address object at 0x11157bef0>
```

Comment: You are just returning the Initializer of the class.

Comment: I don't see any print statement, yet I see the output, coding is really magic :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a small example to address your question.

Suppose I have a class `A` which just has an `init` function. This `init` function takes one input `a` and creates an object `b`.

So the Class looks something like below.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.b = a
```

Now , I have another function `F` , which returns the object from `class A`.

```
def F(a):
    return A(a)
```

when I call this function with

```
>>> F(2)
```

The output will be

```
<__main__.A object at 0x00000202ECF95E88>
```

See , it is just returning the class object.

If you want to access the content, you need to call it in the following way.

```
>>> k=F(2)
>>> k.b
2
```

I hope this answers your question.

Regards